# how to use a field of a table in the parameter of the contains function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I am trying to use a field of a table as parameter of the contains method, but I don't know how to do it.

I am trying this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA AS t1 WITH(UPDLOCK), TableB AS t2
 WHERE CONTAINS(t1.FieldX, '"' + t2.FieldY + '"')
   AND t2.ID IN(1,2,3,4,5);
```

However I get an error that says that is expected a ")" before the first "+".

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it without *contains* and *full-text-search*, I mean using *like* operator:

```
select * from tableA as t1 with(UPDLOCK), TableB as t2
where t1.FieldX like '%"'+t2.FieldY+'"%'
and t2.ID IN(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: When I use like I use full text search? I have the idea that to use full text search I would have to use contains.

Comment: Ok, so I hope you'll get it fixed soon with a way using _contains_.

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is CHARINDEX or PATINDEX...

> where CHARINDEX('"' + t2.FieldY + '"', t1.FieldX) <> 0

not sure if you need the '"'
If you want to use wildcards then use the PATINDEX function
Let me know if this works.

Comment: Do This functions use full text search?

Comment: I get an error with charindex that says I am using a non boolean expresion.

Comment: @Álvaro García True... if the content is found it returns the position. If not found it returns 0... I corrected my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in one query with SQL Server full text. You're essentially trying to run a different full text query against each row.

You would have to actually run a separate query for each row like this:

```
-- put all tableA.ID values in table var so we can loop through them
declare @tableARowsToSearch table (ID int)
INSERT @tableARowsToSearch
SELECT ID FROM tableA WITH(UPDLOCK)

declare @fullTextResults table (ID int, FieldX varchar(max), ...)

-- for each tableA.ID...
declare @currentID int, @fullTextCondition nvarchar(4000)
set @currentID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @tableARowsToSearch ORDER BY ID)
while (@currentID is not null) begin
    -- construct full text condition based on TableB.FieldY
    set @fullTextCondition = (
        SELECT t2.FieldY FROM tableA AS t1 WITH(UPDLOCK), TableB AS t2
         WHERE t1.ID = @currentID
           AND t2.ID IN(1,2,3,4,5)
    )

    -- run full text query against one row in tableA
    INSERT @fullTextResults
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.FieldX, ... FROM tableA AS t1 WITH(UPDLOCK)
     WHERE t1.ID = @currentID
       AND CONTAINS(t1.FieldX, @fullTextCondition)

    set @currentID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @tableARowsToSearch WHERE ID > @currentID ORDER BY ID)
end
```

This is likely going to be very slow. You're better off using LIKE (see Tan_Blaytan's answer) or consider redesigning your tables.